Force dark theme for content in Chrome depending on system settings
I know there is a setting in chrome://flags which forces dark mode for content ("Auto dark mode for Web content", #enable-force-dark). This works pretty well on all websites, even those which don't explicitly support dark mode.
However, this setting seems to be independent of Android's system-wide Dark theme. I would like Chrome to display content in dark mode each time I switch Android to Dark mode, and revert back to normal when Android is in Light mode. How can I achieve this?
Bonus question: is it possible for a website to tell Chrome to follow system-wide Light/Dark theme? This would, at least, solve the problem for websites that I develop.

As I just found out, for websites under your control the following CSS line does the trick: @media(prefers-color-scheme:dark) { body { background:black; color:white; } }. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/prefers-color-scheme
